# How do I convert a Javascript Map to Object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to pass a Map to some code that expects an object. How do I go from

```
new Map([["a", 1], ["b", 2]])
```

to

```
{a: 1, b: 2}
```

?

Comment: `for (var [key, value] of m) obj[key] = value;`

Comment: Is the input `Map` object under your control?  If so, do you use it as such, or could you just use an Object in the first place?  If not, how do you guarantee that the keys are acceptable object keys (Strings/Symbols) and not arbitrary datatypes?

Comment: Answers here look like it's a competition for the most convoluted or most obfuscated solution...

Comment: @DenysSéguret post your solution as an answer!

Comment: @ScottSauyet yup, and tbh my solution is going to be to just use lodash.fromPairs, but I posted this anyway because it was an interesting question. Good point about the key types, I hadn't considered that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) has been included in ECMAScript 2019 so it will be implemented in all major browsers soon.

At the time of writing (April 11, 2019), Chrome 73 and Firefox 63 have already implemented the feature, also BabelJs 7.4

```js
const myMap = new Map([["a", 1], ["b", 2]]);
const myObj = Object.fromEntries(myMap);
console.log(myObj);
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to chain map to array conversions and many function calls, you can use a straightforward loop:

```
var obj = {};
for (var [key, value] of m) obj[key] = value;
```

Be careful that keys will be converted to strings in that process if they aren't already.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Map.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach) like this:

```js
let map = new Map([["a", 1], ["b", 2]]),
    res = {};

map.forEach((value, key) => res[key] = value);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and map the items as new objects.

```js
var map = new Map([["a", 1], ["b", 2]]),
    object = Object.assign({}, ...[...map].map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v })));


console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn that `Map` to array using `spread syntax` and then add to object.

```js
var map = new Map([["a", 1], ["b", 2]])

var obj = {}
var arr = [...map]
arr.forEach(e => obj[e[0]] = e[1]);

console.log(obj)
```